# Java GUI stuck when press a button

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, button, locked

I have a button "Login" in my GUI, when I press it, it goes here:

```
private void loginBtn(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Login log = new Login(robot, driver, username, password, server, url);
    logStatus = log.login();
    Control check = new Control();
    check.loop();}
```

Well, I'd like that when I log in, it logs in and then start playing the loop.
The loop

> check.loop();

is an infinite loop but the GUI stays locked during all the time running it from the action performed of the login button.
So how can i call the loop without lock the GUI?

Comment: post the loop .

Comment: Well, you should not enter an infinite loop inside an event handler. The event runs on the Event Dispatch Thread. It should only be used for quick operations. Otherwise... well... the GUI freezes.

Comment: The `actionPerformed` is already on UI thread. the `check.loop()` should be carried out in a separate non-UI thread. That will relieve the UI. Also an infinite loop ? By having an infinite loop even in a separate thread - it will render a portion of your CPU useless.

Comment: But how can I call the loop after I press the login button if I don't call it inside the event handler? @svasa

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Swing concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)?

Comment: I'm going to try it, thanks.
(This is my first GUI ^^)

Comment: @DavideMelis Take a tour through the [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) and an example also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SwingWorker#Complete_Worker_example)- this is what you need

Comment: Really thank you guys! I was stuck on it for several days